# Upload contents of CSV as new maximum stock position in Exact Online

Tags: csv, exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-data-hub

I want to upload the contents of a CSV file as new values in Exact Online data set using for instance the following SQL statement:

```
update exactonlinerest..ItemWarehouses 
set    maximumstock=0 
where  id='06071a98-7c74-4c26-9dbe-1d422f533246' 
and    maximumstock != 0
```

I can retrieve the contents of the file using:

```
select * 
from   files('C:\path\SQLScripts', '*.csv', true)@os fle 
join   read_file_text(fle.file_path)@os
```

But seem unable to change the multi-line text in the `file_contents` field to separate lines or records.

How can I split the `file_contents`'s field into multi lines (for instance using `'update ...' || VALUE` and then running it through `@@mydump.sql` or directly using `insert into / update` statement)?

Answer (score 2):

For now I've been able to solve it using regular expressions and then loading generated SQL statement into the SQL engine as follows:

```
select regexp_replace(rft.file_contents, '^([^,]*),([^,]*)(|,.*)$', 'update exactonlinerest..ItemWarehouses set maximumstock = $1 where code = $2 and maximumstock != $1;' || chr(13), 1, 0, 'm') stmts
,      'dump2.sql' filename
from   files('C:\path\SQLScripts', '*.csv', true)@os fle 
join   read_file_text(fle.file_path)@os rft

local export documents in stmts to "c:\path\sqlscripts" filename column filename

@c:\hantex\path\dump2.sql
```

However, it is error prone when I have a single quote in the article code.

Comment: In newer release you might want to use read_file_text(name, true) and then feed that into csv_split_row().